# Function Param not defined

Tags: javascript

Why isn't my param working?

```
function myFunc(e){
  e = e || 'add' || 'remove';    
  document.body.classList.e('hide');
}
myFunc(remove);
myFunc(add);
```

if was trying to this

```
function spinner(e){

      let $spinner = document.querySelector('.isolador_spinner');

      if ( e === 'remove' ){
        $spinner.classList.remove('hideSpinner');
      } else if ( e === 'add' ) {
        $spinner.classList.add('hideSpinner');
      } else {
        console.log('e was not defined');
      }

    }
```

It claims e is not a function

Comment: *It claims e is not a function*. The claim seems correct to me!

Comment: so this isn't possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to do. If you try and edit your question according to https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve guidelines others will understand it easier.

Comment: `e = e || 'add' || 'remove';  ` <--- um.... makes no sense... remove will never be used

Answer (score 2):

To access an object property via an indirect variable, use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors):

```
document.body.classList[e]('hide');
```

I'd also suggest using a name other than `e` for your parameter. In JavaScript, a function parameter named `e` conventionally means `e` is an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). Calling it `action` might be a better choice.

The code you added in your edit also has a problem:

```
myFunc(remove);    // wrong - remove is not a variable
myFunc('remove');  // correct
```